# Spring Integration claim-check-in MongoDB message store exception

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-integration

I just want to put GenericMessage into Mongo db msg store, payload is a POJO without fields named 'source' (there is also a chain that outputs to 'pack' channel):

```
<int:channel id="pack"/>
<int:claim-check-in message-store="mongoDbMessageStore" input-channel="pack" output-channel="output"/>

<bean id="mongoDbMessageStore" class="org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>

<mongo:db-factory host="127.0.0.1" port="12345" dbname="mydb" />
```

Getting the following exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException:
>   Ambiguous field mapping detected! Both private java.lang.Object
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanMetadataAttributeAccessor.source and
>   private java.lang.Object
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyValue.source map to the same field
>   name source! Disambiguate using @Field annotation!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, your issue isn't clear for us.

We have in the Framework enough tests on the matter - `MongoDbMessageStoreClaimCheckIntegrationTests`.

So, looks like you POJO isn't compatible with the MongoDB `Document` model.

Please, share your POJO with us. And more logs around the issue.
I means you should switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` to track the messaging travel.

Plus consider to use `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` instead.